# PIC32MX can't get 80 MHz Clock from Internal RC OSC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, oscillator, clock, clock-speed

I am using [PIC32MX795F512L](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61156H.pdf) with the internal RC oscillator. By changing the settings of the config, I can get to 60 MHz max. But I can't get to 80 MHz. When I change the config for 80 MHz, PIC32 just won't run. Here is my config settings for 80 MHz clock speed.

```
    #pragma config FNOSC =  001            // 001       // FRCPLL       // Internal Fast RC oscillator (8 MHz) w/ PLL
    //#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF         // Disable JTAG
    #pragma config FSOSCEN = OFF        // Disable Secondary Oscillator
    #pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF       // Enable CLKO Output on the OSCO Pin
    #pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD       // Enable Clock Switching & Fail-Safe Clock Monitor (FSCM) 
    #pragma config FWDTEN = OFF         // Watchdog Timer Disabled

    //#pragma config ICESEL = ICS_PGx1    // ICE/ICD Comm Channel Select
    #pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_2     // Divide FRC before PLL (now 4 MHz)
    #pragma config FPLLMUL =  MUL_20     // PLL Multiply (now 80 MHz)
    #pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_1     // Divide After PLL (now 40 MHz)
                                        // see figure 8.1 in datasheet for more info
    #pragma config FPBDIV = DIV_1       // PBCLK = SYCLK
```

The same config above runs on the Explorer 16 Board. But It doesn't run in my custom designed PCB.

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? Does the exact same code work if you just change the speed? Do you have access to an oscilloscope so you can enable the CLKO output and look at the resulting speed?

Comment: The Exact same code works on my custom PCB when I change FPLLMUL =  MUL_15. Which would make output Clock of 60 Mhz. I can see that In Oscilloscope. But It just stops working when I cange it back to  FPLLMUL =  MUL_20.

Comment: Could be your layout. What does your PCB look like? Where & what value decoupling caps do you have?

Comment: I have decoupling capacitors on the PCB with 0.1 uF value. I Have kept it On the PCB As close as possible to the PIC32. couple of them might be more then 6mm. is that a big issue?

Comment: @TheRobotPeople No, that sounds fine. The general layout should not be that critical when you use the internal oscillator - you just have to make sure that VDD is stable and well decoupled.

Comment: No Idea what the problem was but I solved it by just soldering all new PCB. It was the exact same PCB but somehow It works in new one.